# jquery change color using css one working but another is not working

Tags: php, jquery

Why only name is changing the color but age is not changing ?

```
<div id="user">
<?php echo $user_name; ?>
<span class="age"><?php echo $user_age; ?></span>
</div>
```

user name color chang is working but age inside span is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#user').css('color','red');
$('#user#age').css('color','gray');  
});
```

Comment: You really need to read jquery documentation urgently, you are confusing on what $('#element') this means and how to call a class like this $('.class')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#user .age').css('color','gray');
```

you have a class 'age' which the selector should start with '.' and it is inside #user, so you need the space between #user and .age .

Answer (score 2):

You are using id where you should use class

```
$('#user#age') // looks for something like <div id="user age"></div> which is invalid
```

Should be

```
$('#user .age') // looks for <div class="age"></div> inside <div id="user"></div>
```

Without any spaces, it looks for multiple properties on the same element.
With the space it looks for the element with the last property inside other elements.
You could also use comma to look for elements with either one or the other property

```
$('#user, .age') // targets both <div id="user"></div> and <div class="age"></div>
```

Comment: The spacing here is also quite important. The first attempt is trying to find the element with the ID of `user` and the ID of `age` (kind-of, it isn't valid).

Answer (score 2):

`#user#age` would match an element which had an `id` of both `user` and `age`.  This is obviously impossible as an element can't have 2 `id`s.  If you want to match an `.age` within a `#user`, you need to put a space between them.

In addition, `age` is a class and not an `id`.  Classes use `.` and not `#`.

Adding all of that up, your selector should be:

`#user .age`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a class use the dot to select

```
$(function(){
  $('#user .age').css('color','gray');  
});
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/35G5j/1/

`#` is for selecting with ID

`.` is for selecting with css class

Comment: `.age` is a child of `#user`, `$('#user .age')` would be correct.

Comment: @Jasper: in this case since age is inside user div, it works, i showed generally thinking there are other areas he has. anyway Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because in your definition `age` is a *class*, not an *ID*, you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user').css('color','red');
    $('.age').css('color','gray');  
});
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

because age is a nanme of a class not the id so you can't use # Have to use .